# How to create cookie before open() in Selenium

Tags: cookies, selenium

This code works only in *googlechrome.

```
$this->browserBot->setCommandLineFlags('commandLineFlags=--disable-web-security');
$this->browserBot->setBrowser('*googlechrome');
$this->browserBot->setHost('localhost');
$this->browserBot->setPort(4444);

$this->browserBot->setBrowserUrl('http://example.com');
$this->browserBot->start();
$this->browserBot->createCookie('foo=bar', 'path=/; domain=.example.com');
$this->browserBot->open('http://example.com/print_cookie.php');
```

In *firefox and *iexplore works only this:

```
$this->browserBot->start();
$this->browserBot->open('http://example.com/blank_page.html');
$this->browserBot->createCookie('foo=bar', 'path=/; domain=.example.com');
$this->browserBot->open('http://example.com/print_cookie.php');
```

Can I create cookie before open() (without redundant open() call) in *firefox and etc.?

Answer (score 3):

This all depends on what is injected into the browser at each time.

The 2nd way that you documented is the way I would do it to make sure it worked over multiple browser versions. I don't think that you can do this the first way for every browser.